# difference between gdb, mdb and soft debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, mono

Mono supports three different debuggers Gdb, mdb(mono debugger) and mono soft debugger. I want to know that are the differences between them?

For debugging C# applications which is better?

**Edit**

On Linux I primarily use MonoDevelop and on Windows for small apps I use either MonoDevelop or SharpDevelop and for larger application Visual Studio.

Comment: well my first question would be are you using VisualStudio to develop .NET apps or are you writing code in some third party tool or Editor..?

Comment: primarily use MonoDevelop as work on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: now is this MonoDevelop for Windows or Ubuntu/ Linux ect..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **[gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)** is the gnu debugger, it has [some mono support](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging#Debugging_with_GDB) and is a very well
  known versitle debugger but not very helpful for C# debugging unless you wish to debug parts of the mono runtime itself.
- **[mdb](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Debugger)** is the mono command line debugger, AKA the 'hard debugger' it can
  debug both managed and unmanaged code.
- **[mono-soft-debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:SoftDebugger)** is the new debugger that is now preferred by
  monodevelop, it can be made debug remote targets (such as android or iphone
  apps) but cannot step into unmanaged code.

Newer versions of monodevelop support gdb for C/C++ programs and the soft debugger for .Net programs.

On linux you will almost always find it easiest and quickest to debug within monodevelop, so you'll be using the soft debugger when doing that. If you are on windows you can of course install mono and monodevelop but also get the added option of using the microsoft debugger in sharpdevelop or visual studio.

Comment: Just an addition: mdb is deprecated in favor of the soft debugger, nobody is working on it anymore (it never worked well anyway).

Comment: I find it sad Mono have reinvented the wheel instead of adding and maintaining a backend to gdb. gdb have different frontends and so many features.